# Bootstrap 5 and wordpress navbar-walker

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

I am trying for the first time to integrate Bootstrap 5.2 in a wordpress site (it is just a local test).
I am doing it through this wp-bootstrap-walker I found: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/

I added the '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php'file the functions it says in the installation guide to the functions.php:

```
 function register_navwalker(){
            require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
        }
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' ); 
        
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => __( 'Main header menu', 'mytheme' ),
        ) );
```

I also changed this in order to use the 5th version:

```
'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
+    'walker'          => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker',
```

So till here there is no error displayed, also in the WordPress back end I can select the 'Main header menu' menu defined in the functions.php, the problem is when I select this option and I go to the main page, then everything crashes:

```
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function walk() on string in C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php:622 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\nav-menu-template.php(242): walk_nav_menu_tree(Array, 2, Object(stdClass)) #1 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-content\themes\my-theme\header.php(61): wp_nav_menu(Object(stdClass)) #2 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\template.php(783): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #3 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\template.php(718): load_template('C:\\laragon\\www\\...', true, Array) #4 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\general-template.php(48): locate_template(Array, true, true, Array) #5 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-content\themes\my-theme\index.php(8): get_header() #6 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-includes\template-loader.php(106): include('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #7 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #8 C:\laragon\www\mydirectory\index.php(17): require('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #9 {main} thrown in
```

Comment: _"I also changed this in order to use the 5th version:"_ -why, what is that supposed to achieve? wp_nav_menu expects an _instance_ of a walker class for the `walker` parameter, not a string.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I was just trying different things, it did not have sence. Thanks to your comment I found the solution, I am posting it!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it writing this:

```
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_navwalker' );
```

I wrote **init** instead **after_setup_theme** to execute the function, also with **wp_loaded** works well.